# Modelling a charging and supplying battery in python

Tags: python, battery, batterylevel

I'm going around in circles trying to model a battery charging and battery usage system given load and supply arrays.

Currently, I have arrays of load and supply and this is what I would like to achieve:

- When my supply is greater than my load I want to be charging my battery, but only with 97% efficiency. As in, if my power surplus at that instant in time is 1kW, the energy surplus in kWh is = 1kW*(1.00 / 60.00). Making my charge = energy surplus*0.97 . Given I'm modelling across 1440 minutes (one day).
- When my load is greater than my supply, I want to draw from the battery to compensate the offset. There is a limit to a how much power I can draw but this is something I will factor in later.
- I would like to keep a running count of the charge in the battery at each timestep. This means that when the battery reaches zero, I can take countermeasures, and when the battery reaches its maximum charge, I can throttle power production. Again the latter two points I want to handle myself later, but the initial count is something I would like help with.

My attempts:
I've tried many times to incorporate an array that factors in the power difference between my load and supply arrays, before then converting each timestep value to energy. Giving me +--+++-+ values etc...
In order to get the total charge of the battery, I've simply used np.sum() and that worked well. 
However, I'm struggling to incorporate a top-end cap that doesn't lock it at that value using if: statements.

So I feel like I'm on the way to getting something but I'm stumbling and fumbling around at the last bit as I'm getting mixed up trying to implement the max cap which is then feeding into other areas.

As always, many thanks for the help! I hope that's clear enough! I think a really basic example will be enough for me to get this sorted. Fundamentals.

I've uploaded an example of what I'm dealing with. A load and supply array, with a scalar battery charge which I would like to change depending on the difference between the load and supply at each timestep. Both charge and draw.

```
import numpy as np 
import random 
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

timebase = 1440 #Hours
t0 = 0 
ts = ts = np.arange(t0, timebase, 1) 
Battery_Charge = 38.40

load = np.array( range(timebase), dtype = float) # Just as an example of the type of array I am using 
supply = np.array( range(timebase), dtype = float) #

def battery(Total_Supp, Battery_Charge, Load):
    values = (Total_Supp - Load) * (1.00/60.00) # Energy draw / charge per unit time 
    charge = np.array( range(timebase), dtype = float ) # Charge of batteries at given unit time 
    charge_eff = 0.97

    for t in range(timebase):
        if values[t] > 0:
            charge[t] = Battery_Charge + np.sum( values[0:t-1] ) + values[t]*charge_eff
        if values [t] < 0:
            charge[t] = Battery_Charge + np.sum(values[0:t])
        if charge[t] > 38.4:
            charge[t] = charge[t-1]

    return charge

battery = (supply,Battery_Charge, load)
```

Comment: Could you please post some code and comment where you're getting readings from? Then it will be more programming oriented and someone can help, to me personally, this seems purely as "design from nothing" question, which is hard to answer.

Comment: Yeah. Give me a second. I've just been playing with it a lot

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).